# Angular PWA load old asset when reopen browser

Tags: angular, angularjs, service-worker, angular-service-worker, ngsw-config

I have an web app using angular 13 and ngsw with caching features.
The problem is when I deployed a new version to production, then I refresh the page, it's updating to a latest version, but when I close the browser than reopen it, it's loading from old assets.

I've tried change the registrationStrategy to 'registerImmediately' but I doesn't changes a thing. How to solve this issue? or should I disable caching?

"@angular/core": "~13.3.11",
"@angular/service-worker": "~13.3.11",

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.